# Automatically adjust minimum on vertical scale in line graph in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dynamic range that feeds the line graph. Depending on the selection in the drop-down menu, it is either LinkedIn Followers (min-max 150,000-200,000) or Engagement Rate (min-max 0.02-0.05) that appear in the same graph. By default the vertical Y-axis begins at zero, so my LI followers metric looks like a flat line at the top of the graph area. If I manually set the minimum to be 150,000, then the followers line looks good, but when the engagement rate is selected instead of LI followers, it appears a flat line at the bottom of the graph area. There are also several other metrics with min-max anywhere in between that can be selected that are also flat lines whether the min on Y-axis is the default 0 or set to 150,000.

Question: How to make the minimum on the vertical Y-axis auto-adjust to the scale of the data like it is possible to do in Excel?

[image: Engagement rate what Y is set to begin at 150,000]

[image: LI followers when Y begins at 0 be default]

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet to try to reproduce it as you have?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138bT3Yip3cg0oObDIS_UtrRTv90EnnfcnXVJePB95Ls/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you found a solution for it? If not have you thought of using an Apps Script [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) simple trigger and then show and hide the chart you want?